# Cannot get multi camera from Nokia 7 plus

Tags: xamarin.android, android-9.0-pie, multi-camera-api

I use C# xamarin and Nokia 7 plus which install android 9 already. Nokia 7 plus contain zeiss dual back camera. So I think I could get multi camera support

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var manager = base.GetSystemService(CameraService) as CameraManager;
        var dict    = manager.GetCameraIdList().ToDictionary((id) => id,(id) => manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(id));

        var lens = dict.Values.Select((characteristics) => (
            (LensFacing)((int)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensFacing)),
            characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.RequestAvailableCapabilities).ToArray<RequestAvailableCapabilities>(),
            characteristics.PhysicalCameraIds.ToArray(),
            characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensPoseRotation),
            characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensPoseTranslation),
            characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensIntrinsicCalibration),
            characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensRadialDistortion),
            characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensPoseReference)
        )).ToArray();
    }
}
```

This code give me 2 camera with 1 front and 1 back correctly. However the capabilities does not contains `LogicalMultiCamera`, `PhysicalCameraIds` is empty set, and all information about lens pose is null

What am I doing wrong here? Or are there any problem about Nokia, Xamarin, or Android SDK?

[image]

Comment: Let me check i out myself and i will get back to you!

Comment: Seems to be the same problem for me on Samsung galaxy s9

Comment: It could be vendor's bug. Try to contact Nokia support. It makes sense to test it on Pixel 3 frontal dual camera.

Comment: @AccessDenied Having repeatedly contact nokia support for month but the issue not progressed

Comment: I have the same issue. You can eliminate Xamarin from suspects: I tried directly with Android Studio (with SDK 28 "P") and REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES does not return LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA (value: 11).